# Why doesn't it work to convert EXE-file to binary code, add to C and re-create?

Tags: c

This is purely experimental and has no real usefulness (at least not according to my knowledge). I’m reading some literature about the PE-format and wanted to try this out if this was possible.

I created a simple program that prints ”Hello World” in C and compiled it to an EXE on a Windows computer, after that I opened the file in a hex editor and saved the content as a C-file (the hex editor has that as an option) and added it as a string in another C script.

The C-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Binary code for C:

```
0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3C, 0x73, 0x74,
0x64, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2E, 0x68, 0x3E, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63,
0x29, 0x3B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x75,
0x72, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x30, 0x3B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x7D, 0x0D, 0x0A [...]
```

This other C script writes out the content in the string to the disk and saves it as an EXE-file that (according to my theory) would be able to execute. However, when I execute it I receive the message ”This app can’t run on your PC”.

The other C-program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen("test_file.exe", "w");

    unsigned char rawData[106] = {
    0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3C, 0x73, 0x74,
    0x64, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2E, 0x68, 0x3E, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63,

    [...]   

    0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x22,
    0x29, 0x3B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x75,
    0x72, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x30, 0x3B, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x7D, 0x0D, 0x0A
    };

    fprintf(file_ptr, "%s", rawData);
    fclose(file_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I mean, it's pure machine code of the EXE-file which worked perfectly before. I guess something must happen in the compiller but I don't understand what exactly.

Anybody who could explain?

Comment: My best guess is that fprintf treats the char array as a null terminated c style string. Check the length of the output against the original file. Also you can use `fc` to compare the binaries if they are the same length.

Comment: Given `fprintf(file_ptr, "%s", rawData);`, `rawdata` isn't a C string - a series of non-zero characters ended with a zero-valued `char`.

Comment: EXE files normally begin with an "MZ" or perhaps "PE" signature byte sequence, your data doesn't appear to match either. Are you sure the data actually corresponds to the file contents of the generated file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifier `"%s"` is for ***null-terminated*** byte strings. The *null-terminator* equals the byte `0` (`0x00`). It's *very* likely that it exists somewhere in the array data. You need some other way to write it, like e.g. [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite).

Also, since you're writing a binary file, you should open it in binary mode as well. Otherwise any byte corresponding to the newline character (`'\n'`, `0x0a` in [ASCII encoding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii)) will be translated to the Windows newline sequence `"\r\n"`.

Lastly, the attributes of the file you create will not include the executable flag.

Comment: Hahaha it works :D I only had to add "wb" (for binary) and replace the "fprint".

Comment: @Lavonen it can't possibly work. See my answer below.

Comment: It did :) To be more precise, I replaced "printf" with "fwrite" (see the answer below) and changed so the file opens as a binary (i.e. "wb"). The results is that the binary code gets copied out as test_file.exe which when executed print "Hello World".

Answer (score 2):

`fprintf` is for writing *text* to a file or stream. The `%s` format specifier will stop on a null character, which is obviously not going to work for binary data which can contain nulls anywhere.

Just the fact that it's binary data should be enough to deter you from using `fprintf` and other text IO functions, but in particular the  PE-EXE format is guaranteed to have nulls within its content by virtue of [its very header](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#PE_Header) which begins with the magic number `"PE\0\0"`.

Use the function `fwrite` to write binary data to a file:

```
fwrite(rawData, 1, sizeof(rawData), file_ptr);
```

Comment: You are correct, I changed that, it still doesn't work though.

Comment: @Lavonen Try opening with mode "wb" rather than "w"?

Answer (score 1):

The "binary" file you are writing is a source file, not an executable. If I translate your raw data:

```
unsigned char rawData[106] = {
0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3C, 0x73, 0x74,
0x64, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2E, 0x68, 0x3E, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x63,
```

It corresponds to the text:

```
#include
```

(etc)

This is not an executable, it is the source file!

You cannot simply save a C source file with an "exe" extension and have it be able to run. You need to actually compile it.

Comment: I see, I used the wrong binary code in the example (the one you quoted was one I used before). The binary code I ended up using was from the compiled code.